# What is the rule for the ending to people in the phrase: много людей

Tags: грамматика, падежи, множественное-число

My question is about **много людей**. Why is there a -ей at the end?

I assume it should be the plural of the masculine человек in genetive case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Человек* is a suppletive word: its different forms are formed from different roots.

There are several pairs like that in Russian:

> - человек / люди
> - ребёнок / дети
> - идти / шёл
> - лежать / класть
>
> etc.

Compare to English:

> - go / went
> - bad / worse

In the modern language the proper singular for *люди* (*люд*) is only used synecdochally (meaning a group of people):

> Пока в Риме правила династия Антонинов, простой люд не жаждал большего порядка в общественных делах. *[Сергей Смирнов. Конец серебряного века. Anno Domini 180 // «Знание -- сила», 2003]*

The proper plural for *человек* (*человеки*) may be only used ironically, exergastically (*все мы люди, все мы человеки*) or to imitate old speech.

> Евангелисты придумали, евангелисты, смертные, как все человеки. *[Юрий Давыдов. Синие тюльпаны (1988-1989)]*

Comment: What about the change of ending from -И to -ей?

Comment: apropos ребёнок/дети - could you explain how ребята fits here?

Comment: @Vitaly: *ребята* is a vernacular word for elder children (above 6 or so), mostly used as an addressing. You won't see it in, say, an official document. *Дитя* is a high style word, not normally used in speech too.

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza: what about it? *Много* requires an object in pl. gen., exactly what we see here. `-ей` is the ending for pl. gen. of nouns with this declension paradigm, compare *чертей, соседей, обручей*.